# Notating the 3rd and 5th of an augmented chord

Tags: notation, harmony, chord-voicings

[image: measures 6 – 9, with augmented chord in second half of m. 7]

I am transposing a piano solo which is in A major. At a certain point (3rd beat of bar 7) the piano plays a dyad which consists of what I would normally call Eb and G natural (a major third apart). The harmony however implies that these are the 3rd and 5th of a B augmented triad. Diatonically, that would mean these notes are D# and F##.

I don't know whether it is clearer to notate it is D# and F## and be more "correct" or instead as Eb and G natural (or D# and G natural?) which I think is easier to grasp quickly, even though it's "wrong".

Which would be generally considered to be clearer?

Comment: Edited to include image of the relevant section. I contradict myself in the right hand by notating it as G natural rather than F, but it felt more "natural" (sorry).

Comment: the second accidental for the second C-natural in bar 8 seems unnecessary/inconsistent

Comment: It doesn't matter, Potato Potato. It won't change the sound.  You notate it in a way that makes most sense to you, generally what is easiest to read the quickest. What makes more sense? B+ or Eb+. They are enharmonic, same chord so it won't matter musically one bit. Although in context which one would be the most natural to understand musically? Eb in the key of A or B in the key of A? Beethoven would probably notate it as Eb+ while Schumann would use B+. No one is going to slap you on the knuckles if you use either one.

Comment: Bear in mind that like the 4 versions of the same diminished chord, augmenteds have 3. Add to that enharmonics, and there's lots of choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would notate the entire two beats as an Eb augmented chord.

- There is ample precedent for using enharmonically equivalent notation to improve readability, especially where double-accidentals are concerned.
- The chord functions as a pivot. Initially, I agree, it's B augmented, inheriting its root from the preceding chord. But it also functions to lead downward to the D chord in the next measure, and then down again to the C augmented chord. By notating as Eb augmented, the downward movement is made more clear, especially the Eb - D - C root movement.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation of the pivot function. Cool how it can be two things at once (kind of). Would you change the right hand notation across those two beats to reflect the Eb augmented chord?

Comment: @yerman Yes, I would notate as Eb augmented (Eb - G - B) throughout.

Comment: Who is the notation and analysis for? If it's ultimately going to improvisers, choose the name that suggests to them what you want them to do with the chord. If it's going to sight-readers, choose the one that's easiest to play without thinking.